# add span tag around all unicodes in a string

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am copy pasting a string from somewhere to a html form. with the post request the string in backend PHP looks like:

```
$string  = "❖ The Low Pressure ❖ Strong ✓ Light";

$string_new  = htmlentities($string);
```

After that i am inserting it into mysql Database with the sql query.

After fetching this string from database with the help of SQL queries, I am printing

In TCPDF php I am doing this:

```
$pdf->AddFont('dejavusans'); 
$pdf->AddFont('helvetica'); 
$pdf->SetFont ('helvetica', '', '10' , '', 'default', true );
```

after getting this string from database with sql query:

```
$string = html_entity_decode($line);
$pdf->writeHTML($string , true, false, true, false, '');
```

Everything went fine untill this.

Now I want to print these symbols with the help of dejavusans fonts and remaining english words in another font. So i need to wrap these symbols to  a span tag with font-family:dejavusans. so that I can achieve my desired output.

So for priting into TCPDF I want my original string to be converted as:

```
$string = "<span style="font-family:dejavusans;">❖</span> The Low Pressure <span style="font-family:dejavusans;">❖</span> Strong <span style="font-family:dejavusans;">✓</span> Light";
```

For doing this i want to wrap all symbols into span tag at the starting.
How to add span tag to this staring:

```
$string  = "❖ The Low Pressure ❖ Strong ✓ Light";
```

Please help.

Comment: str_replace is not very suitable for this, since you need to replace something that is partly dynamic. Go look into regular expressions.

Comment: Please show your code and elaborate on why it doesn't work.

Comment: I have changed the way to ask the question. Please see now and give me idea to do that.

Comment: Don't call it `unicodes`. Unicode is the symbol table. All symbols in it is unicode.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use regular expressions:

```php
function encodeNonWordSymbols($str)
{
    $re = '/([^\w ])/m';
    $subst = "<span style=\"font-family:dejavusans;\">$1</span>";

    $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

    return $result;
}

var_dump(
    encodeNonWordSymbols('❖ The Low Pressure ❖ Strong ✓ Light')
);
```

Comment: Thank you. If few non words symbols already wrapped with span then what should be done.

Comment: And if other basic formatting symbols present then they should not be replaced. Like: "❖ The Low Pressure <span style=\"font-family:dejavusans;\">❖</span> Strong ✓ Light = to (:<speed)" should be converted to "<span style=\"font-family:dejavusans;\">❖</span> The Low Pressure <span style=\"font-family:dejavusans;\">❖</span> Strong <span style=\"font-family:dejavusans;\">✓</span> Light = to (:<speed)"